# What symbol to use for pronunciation help

Tags: phonetics

I am looking to enforce that my letter "a" should be pronounced as "ah".  In my book I am writing I have the name Gorak (Gore-ahk).  What would be the best way to explicitly show that it is Gore-Ahk and not Gore-aek or Gore-ak?

Also if I may, I am also looking to designate the il letter combo to sound like "eel".

I know there are symbols that you place above the letters to help with pronunciation but I am having a hard time googling it to find out what to use with what sounds.  Possibly maybe not asking the right question to google.

Comment: @Laurel, thanks I can see how this would be a duplicate of that.  Not sure how to read that chart provided there, but at least it is a start.  Thanks man.  Sorry for a dup.

Comment: You pretty much can't do this in an unambiguous way. Related questions: [What is the proper way to mark a letter stressed in a name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108591), [Pronunciation Help](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128701), [How to pronounce “aa” vowel pair?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175676), [English regarding the letter i being pronounced as ee](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235213). I would advise including a glossary in the back of your book if you want to include information about the pronunciation of names.

Comment: Your ideas are good for Ah and Eel. Of course, they do rely on recognizing those sounds.

Comment: @YosefBaskin would you recomend i just leave them up to the reader's interpretation?  I do want to enforce proper sound, but at the same time, a native english speaker won't know the meanings of symbols anyways.  I mean heck, I have to google it even myself.

Comment: put a name pronunciation guide in the back of the book.

Comment: Just addressing these two sounds, it's hard to misinterpret and say them wrong seeing Ah and Eel. Some add Ah as in Hurrah, Eel as in Wheel, or such examples.